# Как защитить форму от отправки сверхбольшого текста?

Tags: защита, php, textarea

Привет! Через поле textarea злоумышленник может попытаться отправить сколь угодно большой текст. Чем это может грозить и какие этому противостоять? javascript отключен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если он это делает через CURL например, то можно проверять длину строки на сервере и обрезать её. Если он действительно пытается сделать через форму - [maxlength](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea/maxlength) вам в помощь.

Comment: maxlength можно обойти. На сервере тоже проверяю. Я о том, а не будет ли вывода в браузер сообщения об ошибки, что, мол, превышена максимальная длина post-отправки?